# MyPy shows "untyped decorator" error with a ContextDecorator?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a timer that I use as both a context manager and as a decorator, i.e.

```py
class Timer(ContextDecorator):
    """Context manager which times block execution and
    adds results to APMContext instance"""

    def __init__(self, key: str, apm_context: Optional[APMContext] = None) -> None:
        self._key = key
        self._apm_context = apm_context

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        self._start_time = time.monotonic()

    def __exit__(
        self,
        typ: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
        value: Optional[BaseException],
        traceback: Optional[types.TracebackType],
    ) -> None:
        duration = max(time.monotonic() - self._start_time, 0) * 1000.0
        log_metric(self._key, round(duration, 3), self._apm_context)
```

I'm adding typehints to my project gradually, but when I have a file that uses `Timer` as a decorator, I get the errors

```
results.py:52: error: Untyped decorator
makes function "get_results" untyped  [misc]
        @apm.Timer(key='get_results')
```

If I move the class definition to the file where it's used, `mypy` does not complain, presumably it is finding the correct typeshed forward declaration, but I guess it is not seeing the base class across the import.

Comment: Your `Timer` class doesn't have type annotations.  I'm not sure if that's specifically what's causing the mypy error you're seeing, but it'd make sense to fix that first IMO.

Comment: I do note that `ContextDecorator` doesn't have a type annotation for its `__call__`, so that's probably the issue.  You could probably work around that by either annotating it in your own class (and just pass it through to the parent class) or adding `.pyi` stub to patch up the gaps in `contextlib`.

Comment: Yeah, it's not annotated because I didn't get to that file yet, and adding a `F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])` and then defining __call__ to take/return `F` and call super doesn't work...

Comment: I'll look into the .pyi stub, thanks, my organization has only just started using mypy.

Comment: Oh, typeshed actually does have the correct type stub already: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/contextlib.pyi#L56  So maybe just make sure everything is up to date?  I added some quick annotations to your code to try it in my environment and mypy thought it was just fine (i.e. I can decorate a function with it and the function's type is preserved) without me having to do anything special around `__call__`.

Comment: if I'm importing the module containing Timer from another module, how do I get mypy to understand that it's supposed to be a ContextDecorator from typeshed?

Answer (score 0):

Annotating the `Timer` class should solve the issue:

```py
from contextlib import ContextDecorator
import time
from typing import Any
from types import TracebackType


# replace with the actual definition
ApmContext = Any


# replace with the actual definition
def log_metric(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    pass


class Timer(ContextDecorator):
    """Context manager which times block execution and
    adds results to APMContext instance"""

    def __init__(self, key: str, apm_context: None | ApmContext = None) -> None:
        self._key = key
        self._apm_context = apm_context

    def __enter__(
        self,
    ) -> None:
        self._start_time = time.monotonic()

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: type[BaseException] | None,
        exc_val: BaseException | None,
        exc_tb: TracebackType | None,
    ) -> None:
        duration = max(time.monotonic() - self._start_time, 0) * 1000.0
        log_metric(self._key, round(duration, 3), self._apm_context)


@Timer(key="get_results")  # OK! no errors from mypy
def foo() -> None:
    ...
```

You can read more about typing a Context Manager in [this excellent article](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/07/04/python-type-hints-how-to-type-a-context-manager/).

Comment: it does not. I suspect because __call__ of the `ContextDecorator` class is not annotated?

Or if it does in your case, how about `from my_module import apm` and then decorating your functions with `@apm.Timer(key='get_results')`? Does that also work for you?

Comment: Well, it does work for me. Could you provide the complete code snippet and how do you run mypy? What version of mypy and Python are you using?

Comment: What is `apm` exactly? Is it a class or a module?

Comment: module. mypy is  0.991, python is 3.8.13.

Comment: Try moving the `Timer` class definition to the same file where you call `@apm.Timer(...)` and change it to `Timer(...)`. Does the issue still occur? Perhaps it's an import-related problem.

Comment: Btw, on Python 3.8 use `typing.Union` instead of the `|` operator.

Comment: Yep, moving the definition fixes the errors, but that's not a real solution to my problem. Thinking about just setting `disallow_untyped_decorators = False` in `mypy.ini`, since this doesn't seem to have a common use case. Any way to get mypy to see the base class  through imports, so it can apply typeshed hints?

Comment: It should have no problems with imports. Did you set `ignore_missing_imports = True`? See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports

Comment: That led me to the right path: `follow_imports` was set to `skip`, I had to set it to `silent`. Thanks!

Comment: nevermind, that actually just surfaced more errors that didn't let mypy get to the old ones before exiting. woof.